# Padding and assigning a std::string in c++

Tags: c++, padding

Newbie question. How do I pad a `std::string` in c++ and then assign the padded result to a variable?

I was looking at `setfill` and `setw`, but all examples I saw output the result with `std::cout`. For instance:

`std::cout << std::left << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(12) << 123;`

I wanted something in the lines of:

`auto padded {std::left << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(12) << 123};`

Are there std functions to accomplish this or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: You can use a `std::ostringstream` to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) with the same format specifiers as for std::cout.

```
 std::ostringstream ss;
 ss << std::left << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(12) << 123;
```

And then

```
auto padded{ ss.str() };
```

Answer (score 3):

Could use available string operations, like [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "123";
    s.insert(0, 12 - s.length(), '0');

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/ZhG00V

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and exploit all "utilities" of stream but "export" as `std::string`.

```
std::stringstream aSs;
aSs << std::left << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(12) << 123;
aSs.str();  // <--  get as std::string
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/Qu8Y0e).

Comment: Better use the most specific class that can do the job, here `std::ostringstream`. Don't invoke the generalist machinery of `std::stringstream` without good reason.